Middle mouse button 'sluggish' in vscode?
I'm getting really frustrated with 'middle mouse button' scrolling not being 100% responsive in vscode. It's doubly annoying because it's inconsistent... I have two mouses plugged in (in frustration, and note that one will scroll fine and then become 'sluggish', whereupon switching to the other mouse it's fine (responsive) again. If I use either of these two mice in a browser (for example) scrolling seems fine.
No idea how to diagnose this problem properly. It could be because I'm running a VM under virsh (Wayland unfortunately).
$ code --version
1.92.2
fee1edb8d6d72a0ddff41e5f71a671c23ed924b9
x64


System:
  Host: dan-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009 Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic arch: x86_64
    bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Kvm System: QEMU product: Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009) v: pc-q35-6.2
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: N/A model: N/A serial: N/A BIOS: SeaBIOS v: 1.15.0-1
    date: 04/01/2014
CPU:
  Info: 16x 1-core model: Intel Core i9-10980XE bits: 64 type: SMP cache:
    L2: 16x 4 MiB (64 MiB)
  Speed (MHz): avg: 3000 min/max: N/A cores: 1: 3000 2: 3000 3: 3000 4: 3000
    5: 3000 6: 3000 7: 3000 8: 3000 9: 3000 10: 3000 11: 3000 12: 3000 13: 3000
    14: 3000 15: 3000 16: 3000
Graphics:
  Device-1: Red Hat Virtio 1.0 GPU driver: virtio-pci v: 1
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 23.2.6 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    dri: swrast gpu: virtio-pci resolution: 2560x1440~75Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: kms_swrast,swrast
    platforms: wayland,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1 renderer: llvmpipe
    (LLVM 17.0.6 256 bits)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 82801I HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-40-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active
Network:
  Device-1: Red Hat Virtio 1.0 network driver: virtio-pci
  IF-ID-1: enp1s0 state: up speed: -1 duplex: unknown mac: 52:54:00:da:fd:6a
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 250 GiB used: 17.46 GiB (7.0%)
  ID-1: /dev/vda model: N/A size: 250 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 245.02 GiB used: 17.46 GiB (7.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/vda2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 8 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swap.img
Sensors:
  Src: lm-sensors+/sys Message: No sensor data found using /sys/class/hwmon
    or lm-sensors.
Info:
  Memory: total: 32 GiB available: 31.34 GiB used: 6.64 GiB (21.2%)
  Processes: 431 Uptime: 3d 16h 15m Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.34

I've tried different mices and confirmed that they work in other apps.

I think this is possibly better answered on the VSCode repository.  You can report the issue by going to Help → Report Issue to create an issue tracker in their repo.

Can you provide a link please?

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues
